# How to plot histogram, when the number of values in interval is given? (python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I know that when you usually plot a histogram you have an array of values and intervals.
But if I have intervals and the number of values that are in those intervals, how can I plot the histogram?

I have something that looks like this:

```
amounts = np.array([23, 7, 18, 5])
```

and my interval is from 0 to 4 with step 1,
so on interval [0,1] there are 23 values and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try [`matplotlib.pyplot.stairs`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stairs.html#matplotlib-pyplot-stairs) for this.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

amounts = np.array([23, 7, 18, 5])
plt.stairs(amounts, range(5))

plt.show()
```

Please mark it as solved if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to just simulate some data having the desired distribution, and then use `plt.hist` to plot the histogram.

Here is am example. Hopefully it will be helpful!

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


amounts = np.array([23, 7, 18, 5])
bin_edges = np.arange(5)
bin_centres = (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1]) / 2

# fake some data having the desired distribution
data = [[bc] * amount for bc, amount in zip(bin_centres, amounts)]
data = np.concatenate(data)

hist = plt.hist(data, bins=bin_edges, histtype='step')[0]
plt.show()

# the plotted distribution is consistent with amounts
assert np.allclose(hist, amounts)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the values, then the histogram just becomes a bar plot.

```
amounts = np.array([23, 7, 18, 5])
interval = np.arange(5)
midvals = (interval + 0.5)[0:len(vals)-1] # 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5

plt.bar(midvals, 
    amounts)
plt.xticks(interval) # Shows the interval ranges rather than the centers of the bars

plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot/histogram]

If the gap between the bars looks to wide, you can change the width of the bars by passing in a `width` (as a fraction of 1 - default is 0.8) argument to `plt.bar()`.